# Show contents of div on page load

Tags: javascript

I'm using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUKGt/5/) as a basis for showing testimonials - so when you click on the links the relative testimonials show.

The problem I'm facing is that I need the first testimonial to show when the page loads - at the moment the user has to click on the link to show a testimonial.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fz44h/

```
<body>
<div id="menu_about">
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="first"></a> &#8226; 
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="second">Testimonial 1</a> &#8226;
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="third">Testimonial 2</a> &#8226; 
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fourth">Testimonial 3</a> &#8226; 
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fifth">Testimonial 4</a>
</div>
<div id="pages_about" class="textContainer_about">
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="first">
        <p>Scelerisque arcu lorem porta? Porttitor ridiculus adipiscing diam nisi, turpis, aliquam tincidunt phasellus lundium! </p>
    </div>
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="second">
        <p>Lacus auctor dapibus. Placerat massa lundium lundium in, et. In lacus augue nisi? </p>
    </div>
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="third">
        <p>Placerat massa lundium lundium in, et. In lacus augue nisi?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="fourth">
        <p>Scelerisque arcu lorem porta? Porttitor ridiculus adipiscing diam nisi, turpis, aliquam tincidunt phasellus lundium!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="fifth">
        <p>Lacus auctor dapibus. Placerat massa lundium lundium in, et. In lacus augue nisi? </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.textWord_about').hide();
    $('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();       
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
    width: '200px'
    }, 300);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case this is correct

```
$(function(){
    $($('a.link')[1]).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link:first").click();
});
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the show() method and the document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#menu_about a').first().show();
    //any other statement

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing the first data with data-link attribute should do the trick:

```
 $('.textWord_about[data-link="first"]').show();
```

Code:

```
$('.textWord_about').hide();
    $('.textWord_about[data-link="first"]').show();
    $('.link').click(function() {
        $('.textWord_about').hide();       
        $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
            width: '200px'
        }, 300);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add fadeIn() for first after hiding all without click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.textWord_about').hide();

    $('.textWord_about[data-link="first"]').fadeIn({
    width: '200px'
    }, 300);

    $('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();       
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
    width: '200px'
    }, 300);
    });
</script>
```